# Django: celery task does not execute with .delay()

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, celery, orders

I'm using code examples from the 'Django 2 by Example' book to build my e-commerce shop. The view works as it should, but the task never gets executed. There are no errors. Page is freezing on "Waiting for localhost...". What I'm doing wrong in the code?

**views.py**

```
   import ...
   from .tasks import order_created

        def order_create(request):
            cart = Cart(request)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)

                if form.is_valid():
                    order = form.save(commit=False)
                    if cart.promo_code:
                        order.promo_code = cart.promo_code
                        order.discount = cart.promo_code.discount
                    order.save()

                    for item in cart:
                        OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                                 book=item['book'],
                                                 price=item['price'],
                                                 quantity=item['quantity'])
                    # clear the cart
                    cart.clear()
                    print("clean cart")
                    # set the order in the session
                    request.session['order_id'] = order.id
                    print("id  - check")
                    # launch asynchronous task
                    order_created.delay(order.id) # here I stuck
                    print("clean cart")
                    # redirect for payment
                    return redirect(reverse('payment:process'))
            else:
                form = OrderCreateForm()
            return render(request,
                          'orders/order/create.html',
                          {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order


@task
def order_created(order_id):
    """
    Task to send an e-mail notification when an order is 
    successfully created.
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Order nr. {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Dear {},\n\nYou have successfully placed an order.\
                  Your order id is {}.'.format(order.first_name,
                                               order.id)
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject,
                          message,
                          'archeski.dk@gmail.com',
                          [order.email])
    return mail_sent
```

I'm using
`celery==4.2.0`
`Django==2.0.7`
Ubuntu 18.04

**UPDATED:**
Added this two lines of code in **celery.py**. And freezing has disappear, order page now redirects me for further payment prosedure. But the task `order_created` still not running.

```
  app.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
    # app.conf.broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}  # 1 hour.
    app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

**$ redis-cli MONITOR**

outputs this:

```
OK
1531137225.134559 [1 127.0.0.1:48116] "ZREVRANGE" "book:1:purchased_with" "0" "-1"
1531137240.820217 [1 127.0.0.1:48130] "LPUSH" "celery" "{\"body\": \"W1szMV0sIHt9LCB7ImNhbGxiYWNrcyI6IG51bGwsICJlcnJiYWNrcyI6IG51bGwsICJjaGFpbiI6IG51bGwsICJjaG9yZCI6IG51bGx9XQ==\", \"content-encoding\": \"utf-8\", \"content-type\": \"application/json\", \"headers\": {\"lang\": \"py\", \"task\": \"orders.tasks.order_created\", \"id\": \"172d5ec0-9b53-4766-bc04-470631a3a8e4\", \"shadow\": null, \"eta\": null, \"expires\": null, \"group\": null, \"retries\": 0, \"timelimit\": [null, null], \"root_id\": \"172d5ec0-9b53-4766-bc04-470631a3a8e4\", \"parent_id\": null, \"argsrepr\": \"(31,)\", \"kwargsrepr\": \"{}\", \"origin\": \"gen24500@archeski-Inspiron-5558\"}, \"properties\": {\"correlation_id\": \"172d5ec0-9b53-4766-bc04-470631a3a8e4\", \"reply_to\": \"b8b0c8bb-1931-3be2-a044-d588d95c2fe9\", \"delivery_mode\": 2, \"delivery_info\": {\"exchange\": \"\", \"routing_key\": \"celery\"}, \"priority\": 0, \"body_encoding\": \"base64\", \"delivery_tag\": \"249e3deb-489b-4e0b-bde7-54160d3ccaaf\"}}"
1531137464.423873 [0 127.0.0.1:48192] "SELECT" "1"
1531137464.424085 [1 127.0.0.1:48192] "ZREVRANGE" "book:1:purchased_with" "0" "-1"
1531137479.993181 [0 127.0.0.1:48198] "SELECT" "1"
1531137479.993295 [1 127.0.0.1:48198] "PING"
1531137479.994161 [0 127.0.0.1:48200] "SELECT" "1"
1531137479.994260 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "MULTI"
1531137479.994279 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "LLEN" "celery"
1531137479.994286 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "LLEN" "celery\x06\x163"
1531137479.994291 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "LLEN" "celery\x06\x166"
1531137479.994295 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "LLEN" "celery\x06\x169"
1531137479.994299 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "EXEC"
1531137479.994618 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "SADD" "_kombu.binding.celery" "celery\x06\x16\x06\x16celery"
1531137479.994977 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "LPUSH" "celery" "{\"body\": \"W1szMl0sIHt9LCB7ImNhbGxiYWNrcyI6IG51bGwsICJlcnJiYWNrcyI6IG51bGwsICJjaGFpbiI6IG51bGwsICJjaG9yZCI6IG51bGx9XQ==\", \"content-encoding\": \"utf-8\", \"content-type\": \"application/json\", \"headers\": {\"lang\": \"py\", \"task\": \"orders.tasks.order_created\", \"id\": \"0fbcecc4-293d-472b-8308-46cb2d9ff345\", \"shadow\": null, \"eta\": null, \"expires\": null, \"group\": null, \"retries\": 0, \"timelimit\": [null, null], \"root_id\": \"0fbcecc4-293d-472b-8308-46cb2d9ff345\", \"parent_id\": null, \"argsrepr\": \"(32,)\", \"kwargsrepr\": \"{}\", \"origin\": \"gen24983@archeski-Inspiron-5558\"}, \"properties\": {\"correlation_id\": \"0fbcecc4-293d-472b-8308-46cb2d9ff345\", \"reply_to\": \"f046e6b8-dd2b-30a4-86a5-0de752377bc7\", \"delivery_mode\": 2, \"delivery_info\": {\"exchange\": \"\", \"routing_key\": \"celery\"}, \"priority\": 0, \"body_encoding\": \"base64\", \"delivery_tag\": \"088bae10-976e-4143-8c28-9ed2e254f2d5\"}}"
1531137480.232213 [1 127.0.0.1:48200] "LPUSH" "celery" "{\"body\": \"W1szM10sIHt9LCB7ImNhbGxiYWNrcyI6IG51bGwsICJlcnJiYWNrcyI6IG51bGwsICJjaGFpbiI6IG51bGwsICJjaG9yZCI6IG51bGx9XQ==\", \"content-encoding\": \"utf-8\", \"content-type\": \"application/json\", \"headers\": {\"lang\": \"py\", \"task\": \"orders.tasks.order_created\", \"id\": \"5aa54a37-95da-43c9-b59e-e6797b7cdd2f\", \"shadow\": null, \"eta\": null, \"expires\": null, \"group\": null, \"retries\": 0, \"timelimit\": [null, null], \"root_id\": \"5aa54a37-95da-43c9-b59e-e6797b7cdd2f\", \"parent_id\": null, \"argsrepr\": \"(33,)\", \"kwargsrepr\": \"{}\", \"origin\": \"gen24983@archeski-Inspiron-5558\"}, \"properties\": {\"correlation_id\": \"5aa54a37-95da-43c9-b59e-e6797b7cdd2f\", \"reply_to\": \"f046e6b8-dd2b-30a4-86a5-0de752377bc7\", \"delivery_mode\": 2, \"delivery_info\": {\"exchange\": \"\", \"routing_key\": \"celery\"}, \"priority\": 0, \"body_encoding\": \"base64\", \"delivery_tag\": \"f78cd769-d7fa-43de-aee9-f7bc5a2c78ac\"}}"
```

Comment: Are you sure that the task is stored in the broker?

Comment: Yes, using Redis

Comment: Are you sure that a key is actually created in redis? Check using `redis-cli keys "*"`

Comment: @Lazykiddy returned an empty list

Comment: So are you sure you have a working connection with redis? Every time `some_task.delay()` is called it should store some stuff in redis which should in turn be read by some handler which calls your defined tasks. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7704382/1761364 on how to debug this.

Comment: @Lazykiddy i've update this question, please check the debug info.

Comment: Great! You're successfully storing the task instruction in redis. Is the task discovered by celery? Something with `app.autodiscover_tasks()` in celery.py?

Comment: @Lazykiddy Yes, no errors detected with app.autodiscover_tasks(), but order_created() task is skipped somehow. I've checked it simply with print() function. And e-mail wasn't sent to a customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am studying celery too and started two days ago. My experience is that, you need to independently deploy your celery well before you integrate it into your web application.

After the visit to the celery [doc page](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps) I was able to successfully start my celery application.

Start from the simplest demo.

Answer (score 5):

Can you double-check that you imported the Celery app in your `__init__.py` file like the getting started guide mentions? https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

I was having a similar issue where everything else looked correct, but the task was hanging when I used `.delay()`

Adding the import immediately fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

maybe this helps :

you have to update project conf folder **init**.py file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small incompatibility on Windows and celery4.0+, to solve this problem:

1 - install gevent:

pip install gevent

2 - Run celery:

celery -A <proj_name> worker -l info -P gevent