# How do I access redis server in Django app?

Tags: django, redis

I want to store some feed in redis server, except using global variable for redis server object any other suggestion to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use redis with Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801379/how-can-i-use-redis-with-django)

Comment: I have checked this one, I need to know how to maintain the connection with redis server in Django. currently I define a redis client in a module (redis_client.py), but the connection not stable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use redis as [`Cache`](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache) and then use [django's low level api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) to set and get data.

Comment: I need use the lists type of redis, seems this one not possible.