# Postgres Vs Redis when you have static data

Tags: postgresql, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I already went through many urls like below tried to understand what can I achieved in my project. In My project, I've `25 thousand` records which is pure static data which ***will not*** often gets changed. Around 90% opeations will be of GET (fetch data from using various conditions like `findByUserIdAndGroupId` or `findByUserAndGroupId`, `findAddressByUserId`).

[Why Should I use Redis when I have PostgreSQL as my database for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989390/why-should-i-use-redis-when-i-have-postgresql-as-my-database-for-django)

https://db-engines.com/en/system/PostgreSQL%3BRedis

https://dzone.com/articles/10-traits-of-redis

My current database is `Postgres`(around ***12-15 tables*** only), since data is static `25K records`, we're planning to move into redis (Redis as DB.. i.e., persistance store). But our current Postgres model is so complex, which has `@ManyToMany, @OneToMany and @ManyToOne` kind of relationships with each other*(hardly any data which has no relationship)* and business need bi-directional seaching mostly.

I found found that `Redis` doesn't support queries like `ignoreCase, IN, LIKE` etc. which would need for us as we mostly do the `GET` operations.

So considering above facts, I had the following queries. I know that Redisis not SQL, but I hope relationship can be done in ***Redis using SET*** to some extents. We've plan to use ***Spring Data Redis*** to perform `CRUD` operations instead of traditional `RedisTemplate` Queries.

1) How to model the data (POJO classes using `@RedisHash`) in order to achieve complex relationships. Since I need both ways of searching.

2) We're using PCF, so replication (Master-slave), will there be any issues to deploy redis in three diff data centers. Considering 1 Master & 2 salve?

We did not found any materials over web, which will suggest how to model data in such complex relationship or to what extents, complex modelling is possible. We know Redis is mainly support denarmalization, but what if we need relationship?

[How to model Data in Redis for values Complex Data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265496/how-to-model-data-in-redis-for-values-complex-data-structure)

What will be the advantages of `Redis` over `postgres` under such conditions other than the **Fast-Read** ?..