# Django Temp. Table - Which is Correct Tool- Django-Redis or Redis-Py?

Tags: python, django, redis

I have a webapp using DJango 1.6. This is a simple webapp that makes api calls from a forum and keeps track of threads that are unanswered. I want to store these unanswered thread collections in a redis temporary hash table.

What I am confused about is if I should be using django-redis(which also uses redis-py) or just redis-py. I have read django-redis documentation, and from what I can tell it is for the purpose of using redis to store Django sessions and other backend Django caches. For what I want to do which is just keep a temp. table of forum threads populated by a api call, would the proper tool be Django-Redis or Redis-py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`django-redis`](https://django-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) just provides you with a redis [cache backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/):

> django-redis is a BSD Licensed, full featured redis cache/session
>   backend for Django.

With a redis-py you can "talk" to a redis server, it's a python redis interface.

As far as I understand, question is how you want to interact with redis - directly via the interface or using [django's cache system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#accessing-the-cache). If you want this data to ["expire"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-TIMEOUT) or you want to use redis for caching other entities, or you want to store sessions in redis - use django-redis. Also, there is nothing wrong to use `redis-py` directly or to use both.

Also see:

- [How can I use redis with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801379/how-can-i-use-redis-with-django)
- [Accelerating and Enhancing Django with Redis](http://pyvideo.org/video/1410/accelerating-and-enhancing-django-with-redis)

Answer (score 1):

Also, django-redis allows access to raw redis client: http://niwibe.github.io/django-redis/#_raw_client_access

This allows reuse same connection parameters and same connection pool for both purposes ;)